# Ball can't move in random direction in circle spritekit swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gravity, pong

I am trying to create a game similar to pong in spritekit, Swift. Basically called round pong. User have to handle ball that is moving around the circle area.
Here the issue is, ball is bouncing in same direction in circle. I want that bouncing should be in other random direction to make a game challenging.

Please checkout this video for current bouncing situation : https://drive.google.com/file/d/15fasee1OmKGJQaU4nL34KQgi3-HnBIit/view

Code samples :

```
override func didMove:-

self.physicsBody = borderBody 
self.physicsWorld.speed = 1;
physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

let ball = scene.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -2))
```

Comment: Make your paddle curved slightly

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you for your response. Would you please help in code ? That how to do it? 

This is my current path : 

let path = UIBezierPath() \n
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint.zero,
                    radius: 144,
                    startAngle: CGFloat(-Double.pi / 10),
                    endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 10),
                    clockwise: true)